# How to take a particular array element

Tags: c, arrays

I have declared char array `char BCommand[100]="00LI002LE99"`,i just want to use `002` and `99`.

Here is the code i have tried:

```
 char Lcommand[3],Lecommand[3];
 unsigned char SlaveNodeID=0,NodeValue=0,ChSum2=0;
 Lcommand[0]=BCommand[4];
 Lcommand[1]=BCommand[5];
 Lcommand[2]=BCommand[6];
 Lecommand[0]=BCommand[9];
 Lecommand[1]=BCommand[10];
 SlaveNodeID = atoi(Lcommand);
 NodeValue = atoi(Lecommand);
```

is there any efficient way to do this ?

Comment: I don't understand *take `002` and `99` separately*. Especially the verb *take* confuses me in this context.

Comment: I think the crucial question here is whether you want these extracts as *strings* or as *numeric values / integer*.  If you want strings you're pretty close, you just need to make the receiving variables 1 char bigger, and add a terminating 0 after the extracts (`Lcommand[3]=0`; Lecommand[2]=0;).  If you need integers, see the answers that were already given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think You need `int` values, You can use this if you want integer value of `002`    and `99`.

```
int SlaveNodeID = (BCommand[4] - '0') * 100 + (BCommand[5]-'0') * 10 + (BCommand[6] - '0');
int NodeValue   = (BCommand[5] - '0') * 10  + (BCommand[6]-'0');  

printf("%3d",SlaveNodeID);
printf("%2d",NodeValue);
```

if you want them into strings, then declare character arrays with the size of 4 and 3. use `sprintf()` or `snprintf()` instead of `printf()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use string.h [1] library for manipulating character arrays.

There, you can find functions like strncpy [2], an so you code would be something like:

```
 char Lcommand[3],Lecommand[3];
 unsigned char SlaveNodeID=0,NodeValue=0,ChSum2=0;
 strncpy(Lcommand, Bcommand+2, 3);
 strcpy(Lecommand, Bcommand+7, 3);
 SlaveNodeID = atoi(Lcommand);
 NodeValue = atoi(Lecommand);
```

Also, I would recommend you take a look at other functions from string.h, as they may help you.

[1] - http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/?kw=string.h

[2] - http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncpy/